# Samsung UE590D external monitor settings

Tags: macbook-pro, 4k

I can't get quite the right colors on my external UE590D 4k. Does anyone have the correct settings/colors so it looks as close as possible to the MacBook Pro retina display?

Comment: Have you tried getting your monitors calibrated?  I had a similar issue until I had it calibrated by a photographer friend with a [Datacolor Spyder](https://goo.gl/nuYMts) which I subsequently bought so I could do it myself.

Comment: Seems like a good option, still I'm looking for something simpler. I'm a developer so colors/contrast/saturation are not really my expertise. I'm hoping someone with the same monitor share the settings that worked for him.

Comment: I tried that too,... It was closer, but not enough.  Each display is slightly different from each other.  If it's just for developer work, you may be able to get a photographer or designer to do it for you for a nominal fee, then you will have settings stuff for your display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular Samsung monitor setting the Samsung Magic Angle (Menu > Picture) to Standing Mode and having a low brightness (22) did the trick I have the exact same colors as on the Macbook Pro Retina.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the settings I'm using that's pretty similar.

Picture
Samsung Magic Bright > Custom
Brightness - 22
Contrast - 75
Sharpness - 76

*Color*
Red 69, Green 52, Blue 60
Color Tone - Custom
Gamma - Mode 3 (edited)

Answer (score 1):

Went round and round on this - now the Samsung is matching my Laptop (MacBook Pro 15 Inch 2018) darned near perfectly.

The trick for me was ditching the U28E590 Profile in Display Settings for the monitor and choosing "Thunderbolt Display". This alone got things very, very close.

Then on the monitor, here are my settings:
Brightness: 100
Contrast: 100 (Adjust these two to taste, I like it bright and sharp)
Sharpness: 72
Red: 65
Green: 62
Blue: 62 (Setting these three above 50 gave the saturation a boost)
Magic Angle: Custom

Hope this helps someone.